# trying to attach/mount an EBS volume to ECS instance using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

the aws_volume_attachment resource in terraform requires the instance_id ... my problem is the instance i want to mount the volume to is part of an ECS cluster and i cannot seem to find any clever examples on passing the instance ID of an instance in the ECS cluster to aws_volume_attachment so i can mount an existing EBS volume.

using the ARN does not work.

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdp"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
}
```

**EDIT**
i basically boostrapped a script for the instances and my terraform looked like this:

```
data "template_file" "fleet-boothook" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/boothook.tpl")}"

  vars {
    ecs_cluster_name = "${aws_ecs_cluster.this.name}"
    ebs_volume_id    = "${var.singleton_cluster_ebs_volume}"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the instances in the ECS cluster?

Comment: i have a separate ecs-cluster module written. are you asking what my aws_launch_configuration looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I am also going through this problem, and the conclusion I am coming to accept is that there isn't an easy way to do this. This conclusion is backed by [this issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/64) and [this other one](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/53). I have seen third party solutions [like this one](https://spotinst.com/blog/ecs-persistent-storage-docker-plugins/) but I am not comfortable resorting to third party apps within my infrastructure.

In contrast there is [this repo](https://github.com/zacharysells/tf-ecs) which claims to have achieved a way to provide nodes with EFS. I know it is not EBS, but it could provide a way to share data between containers and a master EC2 instance, regardless of which specific instance the containers are running in.

Maybe you could find a way to attach existing EC2 instances to you cluster so you have more control in provisioning them. This is what I am probably going to try, but I realise it defeats half the purpose of using ecs, which is abstracting the way you launch containers without caring about the underlying host infrastructure.

---

**Edit**:

I managed to create an ECS cluster in which all instances have an EFS partition mounted.

- Create the EFS volume in the same availability region as you are creating your cluster [1]. Be sure to create it in a private subnet.
- Modify your launch configuration `UserData` [2] script to install `amazon-efs-utils` [3]. If you are using ecs optimized amazon linux images, just add the following to your script:

```
  sudo yum install -y amazon-efs-utils
```

- Add a step to create a mount point and mount the previously created EFS volume in `UserData` bash script:

```
  mkdir -p /mnt/efs
  mount -t efs fs-12345678:/ /mnt/efs
```

Change `fs-12345678` to the id of your EFS volume.

I guess you could expose an EBS volume using something like samba, but EFS does not need a dedicated EC2 instance to be served, it receives a dns and can be mounted directly.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/troubleshooting-efs-mounting.html#mount-fails-dns-name

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/using-amazon-efs-utils.html

Comment: interesting! i am buried right now but will come back and digest this. i would say i agree with your first paragraph though.

Comment: reason why EBS is harder to work with is that it represents a physical device in the EC2 instance, while EFS represents a mountable network entity. I believe with EBS you are only able to create a device from a snapshot in the launch configuration, not a shared device across multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

Note that AWS now supports multi-attach for [EBS volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html) - it appears this is officially [not officially](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-access-volumes-using-multi-attach/) supported for multiple EC2 instances though. Note it is only supported for the (more expensive) io1 and io2 disk types.

The EFS solution quoted above is the AWS equivalent of a NFS managed storage solution. The great thing is that EFS is a completely managed storage solution where mb/s can be specified to specify throughput needs. I would be curious to learn if anyone is running high-traffic databases directly on this though.